# jenkins + Allure2 прикрепляет старые тесты

Tags: java, git, jenkins, testng, allure

Проект работает в связке webdriver + testng + jenkins + allure2. Проблема в том, если прогнать локально тест mvn clean test, а потом allure serve target/allure-results, то отчет нормально генерится. А вот jenkins тянет старые suite. Мой pom

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.0-BETA18</allure.version>
    <selenium.version>3.5.3</selenium.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng-suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <argLine>
                    -Djava.library.path=${basedir}/lib
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.3.1</reportVersion>
                <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

[image: Это мой jenkins]

Comment: В дженкинсе воркспейс очищается перед каждой сборкой? Хотя бы не весь, а только неверсионируемые файлы (в эту категорию попадают результаты тестов). Или можно вручную выполнить перед сборкой `git clean -fdx`. (Осторожно, команда удаляет все неверсионированные файлы, как игнорируемые так и нет).

Comment: Мне кажется, что git просто не добавляет репорты, после прогона тестов. Не подскажите, может гдето в jenkinse - в гите есть настройки, чтобы он добавлял, или я нису какой то бред)

Comment: git – это система контроля версий, он не гоняет тесты и не добавляет репорты. Но им можно почистить файлы, оставшиеся от старого прогона тестов.

Comment: А, ну и `mvn clean` должен то же самое примерно делать. Проверьте, делается ли на дженкинсе `mvn clean`. Почитайте логи сборки.

Comment: Алюр 2-й умеет работать с историей запусков тестов ( интеграция с Jenkins из коробки), вы уверены что это не история предыдущих запусков? Если так, то покурите мануал алюра, там результаты запусков мержить можно. Но это точно не проблема Jenkins и темболее testng